# Fork Github and then add in another repo

Tags: github, git-fork

I really hope this makes sense and someone can help as I'm pretty new to Github.

I'd like to start work on a project that has been forked from a repo. The forked version is more UI based (it's now focus on one platform only) . The problem is that the original project has had a fork that updates the engine behind it. The UI is too far along to merge but I think I can hack out the old engine references and add the new forked engine.
Am I able to fork the UI update and then somehow link to the fork of the original(forked) repo?

i.e new repo:

```
./
 /original(forkedENGINE)/
 /original(forkedENGINE)/files
 /original(forkedUI)/
 /original(forkedUI)/files
 /new files
```

or is it work we just forking one and copying the engine or UI over?

Comment: This seems to be a question about GitHub and GitHub forks, not about Git and Linux `fork` system calls, so I updated your tags. I'm not really a GitHub expert but I think the simple answer to your question as asked is "no", though: you can't re-link a GitHub fork to some other GitHub repository. If you want your fork to (eventually) be a fork of repo X on GitHub, you must fork repo X, even if that doesn't get you what you *initially* want. Just add more remotes and use `git fetch` to get the commits you *do* want.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to:

- fork the originla repository (that way, you keep a link to the target repository you want to contribute to)
- add as a remote the project URL that has been forked from the original repository
- fetch from it and start hacking, using the original repository codebase as your current code, and importing/merging the bits you need from the project
- push and make PR to the original repository.